# Set classpath permanently in Linux

Tags: java, linux, classpath

I am using centos and I have 4 to 5 jar files which I want to add permanently in classpath, So that I can run my program from anywhere. I tried this-

```
 export CLASSPATH="/path/to/file:/path/to/file2"
```

Above command worked perfectly but I think it was not adding files permanently. When I opened new tab and tried to compile my program then I was getting same error i.e jar files were missing.

Now, Please help me to add these jar files permanently to classpath.

Comment: add it to your ".bashrc" file and close and reopen your terminals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add that `export` statement to the end of your bash init file `~/.bashrc`, therefore it will in effect all the time.

By the way, a better setting of `CLASSPATH` would be

```
export CLASSPATH="/path/to/file":"/path/to/file2":"${CLASSPATH}"
```

this will also preserve the initial value of that environment variable.

Comment: Yeah, it worked. No error at compile time but when I am trying to run the program then I am getting Error: Could not find or load main class programName. Is this error related to classpath ?

Comment: @HimanshuMatta I do not believe it is. However, if you cannot figure out the reason, I think you should fire another question :-)

Comment: Ohkay..Working now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: are the quotes necessary? won't export CLASSPATH="/path/to/file:/path/to/file2:$CLASSPATH" be sufficient?

Comment: @NaveenDennis Yes, if you prefer that way.

Answer (score 1):

Add your path to /etc/profile and reboot to take effect

```
export CLASSPATH="/path/to/file:/path/to/file2"
```

Comment: rebooting is definitely not necessary. you can log out/login.